# PFFile size issues with parse and swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Why is it some pictures I have taken on my iphone are too big to upload to parse as a PFFile. The limit is 10 mgb and I know these pictures can't be that big. Some are small enough but most are not. Is there anyway to optimize the size for parse? Here is my code

```
//--CONTROLS HOW TO PICK THE IMAGE WHEN THIS BUTTON IS CLICKED--\\
@IBAction func chooseImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    var image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false
    self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


   @IBAction func postImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    var error = ""
    if photoSelected == false{
        error="Please select an image to post."
    }
    else if contactText.text == ""{
        error = "Please enter an email or phone number."
    }
    else if nameOfPost.text == ""{
        error="Please enter the name of the post."
    }
    else if descriptionOfPost.text == ""{
        error="Please enter a description about your posts."
    }

    if error != ""{
        displayAlert("Oops! There was an error with posting.", error: error)
    }
    else{
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 125, 125))
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
        activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (158/255.0), green: (40/255.0), blue: (52/255.0), alpha: 1)
        activityIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

//--MAIN CODE TO POST--\\
        var post  = PFObject(className: "Posts")
        post["Contact"] = contactText.text
        post["Name"] = nameOfPost.text
        post["Description"] = descriptionOfPost.text
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageToPost.image)
        let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData)
        post["imageFile"] = imageFile
        post["createdBy"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId


        //--GETTING LOCATION OF THE POST--\\
        PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
            (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                post.setValue(geoPoint, forKey: "Location")
                post.saveInBackground()
                println("found location")
            }
        }

        //--SAVING THE Post HERE--\\
        post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success:Bool, error:NSError?)-> Void in
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            if success == false{
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                self.displayAlert("Sorry! We could not post.", error: "Please try again later.")
            }
//--NO ERRORS SO NOW WE CAN SAVE AND POST==\\
            else{
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToFeed", sender: self)

            }

        }
    }

}
```

I really need to be able to take pictures for my app but every picture I take from the camera is too big.

Comment: You could resize the image before saving to Parse.

Comment: How would I go about doing that. This is user driven

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=resize+uiimage+ios&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#safe=off&q=resize+uiimage+ios+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: where is the rest of your code? what is post?

Comment: post is a class within parse

Comment: @user2967062 is it a PFObject? How did you created and saved it? You need to add more code so we can help you!

Comment: @Icaro Yes it is a pfobject. I edited the code to show you everything you should need to know

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a little fish to me, I would do like this:

```
var post:PFObject

func prepareToSavePost(){
    post  = PFObject(className: "Posts")
    post["Contact"] = contactText.text
    post["Name"] = nameOfPost.text
    post["Description"] = descriptionOfPost.text
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageToPost.image)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData)
    post["imageFile"] = imageFile
    post["createdBy"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId

    //Get bytes size of image
    var imageSize = Float(imageData.length)
    //Transform into Megabytes
    imageSize = imageSize/(1024*1024)
    println("Image size is \(imageSize)Mb")

    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
        (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.post.setValue(geoPoint, forKey: "Location")
            println("found location")
            savePost()
        }
    }
}

func savePost(){
    post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (success:Bool, error:NSError?)-> Void in
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                if success == false{
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                    self.displayAlert("Sorry! We could not post.", error: "Please try again later.")
                }
    //--NO ERRORS SO NOW WE CAN SAVE AND POST==\\
                else{
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToFeed", sender: self)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Why I would do like that? It seems that you can run in a deadlock trying to update the location and the other details at the same time, in other words running save command in the background twice in parallel.

Will this fix your problem? Maybe, parse.com does not always send the errors as it really is

I also add a log for the image size but you can transform that in a if and pop up an alert view or resize the image if it is bigger than 10Mb (what I don't think will happen in the iPhone)

Comment: It said that pffile doesn't have the member of length.. This is found in this line                       var imageSize = Float(imageFile.length)

Comment: @user2967062 sorry it should be imageData  not imageFile, I already update the answer

Comment: no problem. it also said something about not being able to use a local function inside of another local function